# How to put ajaxStart() for one element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 differents ajax in the same page. One is for some input text, the other one is for checkboxes. I am using ajaxStart() to show my loading gif, then ajaxStop() to hide it. The problem is in my input text it's loading the gif but I don't want it.

This is my ajax code

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        loading.show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        loading.hide();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send/getBlocHtml",
        data: {'id': blocID},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(bloc) {
            var bloc_title = bloc.title.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var blocHTML = $('#sortable').find('div[data-bloc='+bloc_title+']');
            blocHTML.removeClass('activate').addClass('disable');
            blocHTML.fadeOut();
            if($('#sortable').children().length == $('#sortable').children('.disable').length) {
                $('#sortable').fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there anytyhing I could add inside ajax() to show my loading and to hide it when ajax is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeSend` to show your loading image and you can hide it inside `success`.